# How to sum the array value in javascript like chartjs data array and input value sum

Tags: javascript, arrays, chart.js

I am trying to make a chart using chartjs and I feel some issue and try a lot to fix the issue, need help,

here is the demo for what I want.

**HTML**

```
<div id="demo">Demo here</div>
<input type="number" onkeyup="myFunction(this)">
```

**Js**

```
let num = [3, 2, 5, 3, 2, 5, 3, 45, 2, 3, 4, 2];
function myFunction(t){
  for (let i = 0; i < num.length; i++){
    num[i] = num[i] + parseInt(t.value);
    demo.innerHTML = num[i];
  }
}
```

this is just demo, which I need to fix,
I need to sum the array value like 
every num let value will add like input value + every array sum,
for example,
If I input 5 it will sum and will looked

`let num = [8, 7, 10, 8, 7, 10, 8, 50, 7, 8, 9, 7]`

I try a lot to fix and see many stackoverflow post but didn't get the right suggestion.
Recently, I am trying to make chart with input control and unable to control all data array, need help

Comment: What? Do you want to sum all the values in the array + the input value?

Comment: here, chart.js  one data working but I need to apply all data and all data will sum with input value, ```let pastData = startChart.data.datasets[0].data[0]; // first data

function salaryF(salary) {
    let presetData = startChart.data.datasets[0].data;
    presetData[0] = parseInt(salary.value) + pastData;
    startChart.update(); 
}

// salaryF(salary) // input control onkeyup function ```

Comment: What is the question? *"I feel some issue"* is not very specific. What is the expected result? What is the current result?

Answer (score 3):

```js
let num = [3, 2, 5, 3, 2, 5, 3, 45, 2, 3, 4, 2];

function myFunction(t){
  console.log(num.map(elem => elem + parseInt(t.value)));
}
```

```html
 <input type="number" onkeyup="myFunction(this)">
```

This is what you need right ?

Comment: it will work , but in my chart.js custom script I try like this but not working , only work one data, here is the code ```     function salaryF(salary) {
    let pastData = startChart.data.datasets[0].data; // first data
    pastData[0] = parseInt(salary.value)
    startChart.update();
}                   ```

Comment: console is working but my chart not working all data only working specific one data what's the solution?

Comment: I think there you use `demo.innerHTML = num[i];`. That means every time you modify the innerHTML of that element. That's why you see one record. Do you see only last value ?

Comment: hi mate, I see the last one showing me but the chart not effect anything, here is the code which I tried, ```                   function salaryF(salary) {
    let  chartData = startChart.data.datasets[0].data;
    console.log(chartData[chartData.length - 1]);
     chartData.map((e) =>{
        e + parseInt(salary.value);
    // console.log(e + parseInt(salary.value))
     startChart.update();
    });

    
}                                 ```

Comment: Can you include your html snnipet too ?

Comment: ok, See this one, ```     
function salaryF(salary) {
    let  chartData = startChart.data.datasets[0].data;
    chartData[chartData.length - 1] = parseInt(salary.value);
     startChart.update();
}
        ``` actually when I am going to concate that time it's not working but if I use asignment than working but not working all data

Comment: Hello, I didn't find the snippet options, I didn't use it before,  here is the codepen ` https://codepen.io/nikhilroy2/pen/GRgXyXz?editors=1010 `